# How to get the value from onlongitemclicklistener in GridView item

Tags: android, android-gridview

In Fragment `onCreateView`:

```
GridView gv = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gvEntries);
gv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("com.myapp", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("theDate", ""); //get the "the_date" from position
        editor.putString("TheValue", ""); //get the "the_value" from position
        editor.commit();
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).openDialog(1);
        return false;
    }
});
Cursor crs = dbh.getC("1");
PopulateGridView pgv = new PopulateGridView(getActivity(), crs);
gv.setAdapter(pgv);
```

Adapter class:

```
public class PopulateGridView extends CursorAdapter {
    public PopulateGridView(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.disp_data_in_grid, parent, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Find fields to populate in inflated template
        TextView tvVal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvGVal);
        TextView tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvGDate);
        // Extract properties from cursor
        String strVal = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("the_value"));
        String strDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("the_date"));
        // Populate fields with extracted properties
        tvVal.setText(strVal);
        tvDate.setText(String.valueOf(strDate));
    }
}
```

XML item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_selector">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvGVal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvGDate" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How do I get the textview values from each item onlongitemclicklistener, for the following:

```
editor.putString("theDate", ""); //get the "the_date" from position
editor.putString("TheValue", ""); //get the "the_value" from position
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
 @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
TextView tvVal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvGVal);
        TextView tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvGDate);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("com.myapp", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("theDate", tvVal.getText().toString()); //get the "the_date" from position
        editor.putString("TheValue", tvDate.getText().toString()); //get the "the_value" from position
        editor.commit();
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).openDialog(1);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Yes I did... simple and easy. I had to edit your answer to make it correct 100%. Thanks.